# Preventing a Burp and Intercept

Tags: authentication, api, burp-suite, tls-intercept

I have created an authentication API to manage user sessions and the works. To log a user in, the user send their credentials to my API endpoint and it returns “true” or “false” based on their login. I recently received an issue report stating that using “a burp and intercept”, the response of “false” can be changed to “true”, bypassing a failed login attempt and tricking the browser into thinking the user is logged in.

I’ll be honest: I have no clue how to prevent this. And if I cannot prevent it, is there a better way to be authenticating users?

Comment: Will they be able to access confidential information afterwards?

Comment: It should not matter what the browser thinks. On successful login, you should return a token to the browser to be presented on further requests (usually stored in cookies). If the login fails, you do not return a token and the browser will get a 401 from the server. You may want to [read up](http://blog.restcase.com/restful-api-authentication-basics/) on web api authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to ask the reporter to explain what they think the security implications are.

Tricking the browser into showing a successful login via a locally forged API response does no harm unless the user can use that to actually bypass authentication or access confidential information. An attack would have to trick the *server* into assuming the authentication succeeded, not the client.

> I have no clue how to prevent this.

You can't prevent a user from tampering with data which has left your server. You have no control over the client (their browser) and can't stop them from using Burp ([or the developer console for that matter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175471/important-data-can-be-modified-from-the-developer-console-what-should-i-do)) to rewrite requests and responses in ways that you web application didn't intend.

> And if I cannot prevent it, is there a better way to be authenticating users?

As Marc outlined, one possible approach is to have the API endpoint return a session token once the authentication succeeds. The client would then use this token to make further authenticated requests.

Answer (score 1):

Security Researcher 'Joel Aviad Ossi' from https://websec.nl has shared a code that does exactly this on his github:

https://github.com/websecnl/BurpBuster

Comment: interesting.  One way to defeat BurpBuster, then, is to add a match and Replace rule to mess up that javascript code....   I added a Match and Replace for the Response body that replaced isLoaded == true with 0 == 1 and BurpBuster stopped working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).